# Benefit of writing (1<<24 - 1) instead of FFFFFF?

Tags: c

I have a piece of code in C with the following:

```
a = b & ((1<<24) - 1);
```

If I am not mistaking, this is equivalent to:

```
a = b & 0xFFFFFF;
```

What is the benefit in terms of performance to write the first one? For me it is more complicated to read, but I suppose the guy who wrote that had a better C background than I have.

Thanks

Comment: They will compile to identical code, there is no performance benefit. I would write it your way (`0xffffff`), but it's been a while since I worked in C, I'm curious what reasons others might come up with for writing it the first way.

Comment: The only reason I'd write it with the bitshift is if I were making a macro or function parametrized by a bit count `N` rather than a constant 24.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all of you for your explanations which converge to show that it's only a way to understand the operation is done on 24 bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In all likelihood, there isn't any performance difference since the compiler will figure out that `((1<<24) - 1)` is a constant expression, and will evaluate it at compile time.

We can only speculate about why the original author of the code chose to write it the way they did. Perhaps they thought it better expressed the intent ("mask out all but the 24 least significant bits of `b`").

If that was their reasoning, I personally would tend to agree with them.

Comment: It's required to be able to make this determination, since knowing what's a constant expression is essential to initialization of static-storage-duration objects. A compiler would have to be maliciously bad to choose to evaluate this expression at runtime.

Answer (score 14):

There is no difference in performance since the compiler will perform the calculation for you.

The first option may be used to explicitly clarify that you are using 24 set bits. This is harder to count in the second option.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any benefit from the performance point of view, as aix says.

To me, anyway, it appears clearer in the first version better communicates that the constant value is 2^24-1 than the latter form. Of course, I guess this is just an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't part of a larger block of code, I like your use of `0xFFFFFF` better.

But, it can conceivably be part of a group of similar statements. Then the shift version is (arguably) better.

```
switch (binaryprefix) {
    default:       a = 0;                   break;
    case DECABIN:  a = b & ((1 <<  1) - 1); break;
    case HECTOBIN: a = b & ((1 <<  2) - 1); break;
    case KILOBIN:  a = b & ((1 <<  3) - 1); break;
    case MEGABIN:  a = b & ((1 <<  6) - 1); break;
    /* ... */
    case ZETTABIN: a = b & ((1 << 21) - 1); break;
    case YOTTABIN: a = b & ((1 << 24) - 1); break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No benefit in performance for doing `((1<<24) - 1)`. It might be slower since it has to perform some operations (`<<` and `-`), while `0xFFFFFF` is a constant. Best case the compiler will calculate the 1st at compile time and they'd be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should avoid using statements like the first.

The only scenario that i can think of that the first sentence would be preferable, is if the number 24 has a meaning. (Which should have been defined and named anyway.)

Like, if for some reason in this line of code it can be 24, and in a different place it might be 22.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the expression

```
(1<<24)
```

is non-portable and may be undefined behaviour, because 1 is treated as an int, and the standard guarantees only 16 bits for an int. If you still happen to code for such an implementation... If a and b are ints, then you can safely deduce that the target are more modern implementations only, having ints with 32 or more bits, of course.

Comment: It is a legal C expression and can be used in a perfectly portable manner. Consider `(sizeof(int) >= 4 ? (1<<24) : (1<<8))`.